# A very basic Type check fails in F# ... why?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

I wrote this code

```
type Test =
    | Age of int
    | Name of string;;

let x = Age(10);;


if (x.GetType() = typeof<Test>) then printfn "true" else printfn "false";;
```

The code prints false. But that puzzles me because isn't Age of type Test?

Also, is there a better way to compare types in F# the `.GetType() = typeof<>` is very long. I tried `:?` but I think that's for typecasting rather than comparing types.

Comment: if (x.GetType() = typeof<Test>) then printfn "true" else printfn "false";;

prints false.

Comment: > if (x.GetType() :? Test) then printfn "true" else printfn "false";;

  if (x.GetType() :? Test) then printfn "true" else printfn "false";;
  ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(52,5): error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. The type
    Test
is not compatible with type
    System.Type
The type 'Test' is not compatible with the type 'System.Type'

Comment: Did you look at the result of `x.GetType()`? Do so.

Comment: match x with
| :? Test -> true
| _ -> false;;

stdin(59,3): error FS0016: The type 'Test' does not have any proper subtypes and cannot be used as t
he source of a type test or runtime coercion.

Comment: x.GetType();;
val it : System.Type =
  FSI_0031+Test+Age

The type is Test+Age. humm... now how to compare and test if its Age or Name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plain answer is, do so:

```
if (x :> obj) :? Test then printfn "true" else printfn "false"
```

This issue comes because of the implementation of DUs (using internal classes and tags) and the limitation of F#'s type system (which does not acknowledge the implementation).

As you saw, the type of `x` is `FSI_0001+Test+Age`, and F# does not recognize that as a sub-type of `Test`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the `Type.IsSubclassOf` method, e.g., `x.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof<Test>)`.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the spec

> A compiled union type U has:
>
> · One CLI static getter property U.C for each null union case C. This
>   property gets a singleton object that represents each such case.
>
> · One CLI nested type U.C for each non-null union case C. This type
>   has instance properties Item1, Item2.... for each field of the union
>   case, or a single instance property Item if there is only one field.
>   However, a compiled union type that has only one case does not have a
>   nested type. Instead, the union type itself plays the role of the case
>   type.

We see that `Age` is implemented as a nested type of the parent DU.  As a result you could use `Type.GetNestedTypes` to get all the subtypes of the DU and then test each one to see if the type matches.

Answer (score -2):

> But that puzzles me because isn't Test of type Color?

There is no type `Color` and `Test` is a type itself so it does not have a type. So your question is nonsensical.

Perhaps you meant to ask why the answer is what it is? If so, it is a consequence of the way F# currently chooses to represent such values internally.